# Can I create a List within a folder?

Tags: list, content-type

I have a Library called Documents. Within "Documents" a folder called "Lists". 
I have enabled List View (forget actual phrase used) as a content type in the lists folder.

A user created a list through Settings >Add an App >Custom List.

The list appears in the left-hand column underneath my Library. May I move the list into the folder called "Lists"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Lists are stand-alone objects and cannot be nested within each other. You may however create a link to the list within your lists folder. The left-hand column where the list showed up is just a link as well - the list lives within your site (probably at `http://server/sites/yoursite/lists/yourlist`).

Comment: Thanks. I was going crazy trying to figure out how to do this because our user insisted that it used to work. I realized just a few minutes ago that the user did not know what he actually wanted to do. sheesh.

Comment: This is something Sharepoint should add, it is actually kinda annoying to not be able to manage lists in folders. Specially when you have almost a hundred different lists.

Answer (score 1):

You could also achieve this using a Document Set, which is a content type that stores documents (much like folders do). The landing page of the document set is editable, and webparts can be added to it.

Once you've created your Document Set, simply add an App Web Part for the list you want to display to the landing page.